# Docker-compose mount test results inside a local volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, mounted-volumes

I have python tests that generate the results of the tests as HTML and XML files. When I run docker-compose, I want to find these results and mount them in a local volume.

docker-compose.yml

```
version "3.9"
services:
  tests:
     build: .
     image: test-image
     volumes:
       - myLocalVolumes:/my/url/to/tests/results
volumes:
   myLocalVolumes
```

I am using a MacBook. Any tips on how to find the URL of these test results.
I think it has to be taken from inside the container or stored somewhere in the computer.

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to save test results. first find where the results are saved in the container. if your script/code write results to folder called `results` in the same working directory
you should first find the working dir
you can find it in the Dockerfile
example:
`WORKDIR /project`
then mount the `results` directory to the docker volume

```
version "3.9"
services:
  tests:
     build: .
     image: test-image
     volumes:
       - myLocalVolumes:/project/results
volumes:
   myLocalVolumes
```

you will find volume in the path `/var/lib/docker/volumes/myLocalVolumes`
or in more simple way you can mount to a folder in the host machine

```
version "3.9"
services:
  tests:
     build: .
     image: test-image
     volumes:
       - ./results:/project/results
```

if your script/code generates individual files with different unique names it's better to modify the code to put results into a directory so you can mount them easily.

Comment: Are you saying to mount the data, I should do:
```
volumes:
       - myLocalVolumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes/myLocalVolumes
```
Maybe I was not clear. Below are the parameters of the volumes:
```
volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /data
```
Which equals in short-code to 
```
Volumes:
  - mydata:/data
```
So my source is /myLocalVolumes and I am asking what should be my target path if my goal is to save the results(some HTML and XML files) of the tests located inside the container.

Comment: Thanks, @AhmedAbdelazim !!! Your response is very similar to what worked for me. There is a folder named results inside the project. All I had to do is myLocalVolumes:/results . I will provide a complete response below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is there is a folder named ***results*** inside the project. That folder contains all the results of the tests as HTML and XML files. To mount that data, we will do: myLocalVolumes:/results.
The complete docker-compose.yml will be

```
version "3.9"
services:
  tests:
     build: .
     image: test-image
     volumes:
       - myLocalVolumes:/results
volumes:
   myLocalVolumes
```